# Can we show UIAlertController from app extension with no user interface like "Action Extension"?

Tags: ios

I am developing an application extension for iOS with no user interface. For its functionality I do not need any user interface as all of the tasks are done in the background.

The only scenario which requires a UI is to alert the user if some configuration is missing from the device. Can I show the `UIAlertController` from such an extension or do I have to configure the extension to use user interface?

Comment: any change you found out how to do it ? because I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

When I'm using something that needs a "popUp"-like effect but can't use UIAlertController for some reason I use [this SDK](https://github.com/m1entus/MZAppearance)

Its really good and the documentation is quite complete.

Comment: @SeniorCoder  Hi, I am using Network Extension and it has no UI so no AppDelegates and no viewController. As a result I can not use this approach. Looks like this can be the restriction from those extensions itself.

Comment: you can create a UIView that will appear like the UIAlertController but where you have all the control. Thats is the only possibility that I can see for now

Answer (score -1):

To display the Alert in any class, not in UIViewController, you have to get the top viewcontroller from app delegate and use it for alert.


Best way is using AppDelegate. Please try to use this.

```
func showAlert(message:String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Notification", message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    let topViewController = self.topViewController((self.window?.rootViewController)!)
    topViewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func topViewController(rootViewController:UIViewController) -> UIViewController {
    if let presentedViewController = rootViewController.presentedViewController {
        if presentedViewController.isMemberOfClass(UINavigationController) {
            let navigationController = presentedViewController as! UINavigationController
            return self.topViewController(navigationController.viewControllers.last!)
        }else{
            return self.topViewController(presentedViewController)
        }
    }else{
        return rootViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no AppDelegate for app extensions